# Passing Arguments to guest execuatble in service fabric

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

i have a console application which i am deploying in service faric as guest executable.It accept two parameters, when deploying using visual studio we can pass arguments under ExeHost tag inside Servicemanifest.xml file. How to achieve the same through c# code using  CreateApplicationAsync or any other methods[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI0dy.png)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI0dy.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use many options:

- Use config files
- Query from database
- Change the service manifest at
  deployment time